# set up wordpress blog inside exisiting rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

I have a website which is a rails middleman app. A static website.

I have another blog which is for the marketing folks to post blogs as they require. Now, our folks want the `wordpress` to be a part of website, but still be able to publish posts from their side.

current URLs:

website: www.abcd.com/xyz

blog: blog.xyz.io

expected URLs:

website: www.abcd.com/xyz

blog: www.abcd.com/xyz/blog

Is there a way in `wordpress` so that we can change the instance to be shown from a different domain? or a way to put in `wordpress` instance as part of the middleman app ?

Comment: You can mount wordpress on any given path by defining the  `WP_SITEURL` constant in `wp_config.php`. I'm not sure though if its possible to get middleman to forward / ignore requests for a particular path. There is arguably many better choices than wordpress for a blog in 2018 though as the code is a bog and its usually slow as hell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible to set wordpress at a URL inside of your main Rails app.

However, you could use Wordpress' built in API and display the posts on your page using it.

When the page load, fetch the posts needed from the blog's API and display the result.

See:
    https://v2.wp-api.org/